# C++ avoiding manually calling base class function

Tags: c++, design-patterns, inheritance

I have a set of classes like this:

```
class A {
 public:
  int DoIt() {
     //common code
  }
};

class B : public A {
  int DoIt() {
    if (A::DoIt() == 1) {
      return 1;
    }
    else {
      // do b specific code
    }
  }
};

class C : public A {
  int DoIt() {
    if(A::DoIt()==1) {
      return 1;
    }
    else {
      // do c specific code
    }
  }
};
```

Is there a way I can avoid manually putting this code:

```
if (A::Doit() == 1) { return 1; } else {
```

in every class which is derived from A?

Comment: The correct syntax is `class B : public A`. C++ is not Java.

Comment: @Justinᚅᚔᚈᚄᚒᚔ: OP is asking how to avoid typing `if(A::Doit()==1) return 1; } else {` in every subclass, not how to call `A::Doit()` without knowing A. The linked question isn't even related to inheritance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just separate the specific code to another method virtual method.

```
class A
{
public:
    int DoIt() /*final*/
    {
        // common code
        if (return_value == 1)
           return 1;
        else
           return DoIt_specific();
    }

private:
    virtual int DoIt_specific() = 0;
    // ^ or some "A"-specific actions if A cannot be abstract.
};

class B : public A
{
    virtual int DoIt_specific() /*override*/
    {
        // specific code for B
    }
};
```

This is known as the [non-virtual interface](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Non-Virtual_Interface) idiom.